# Adapting WP7 App to Website Change

Tags: xml, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7 app on the Marketplace that accessed an online XML file and displayed the contents within the app.  However, the website just made a change to the way it displays the data, and the XML file is no longer available.  It is now instead displayed within the content of a table, and I'm not quite sure where it obtains the data from.  Is there any way for me to adapt my app to still retrieve the contents of this new table, or another way for me to display the data?  Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If it's in a table on the web page then you'll need to parse the html. You could hand code this or look at a tool such as [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Be mindful of the site's permission for you to reuse their data for whatever you're doing.

Comment: Very helpful information, Mick.  Thank you very much for your help, I'll get right to looking into this.

Comment: +1 for verifying the permission when using content from 3rd party websites.

Comment: Yea, seen some stories of devs being buried in legals on other platforms. Worth checking your sources on this.